# confusing inner join in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I use inner join in pyspark shell like this:

```
tab_df=ori_df.join(ori_df,ori_df.columns,'inner')
```

Since I use the same table for inner join , it should be expected that the `tab_df.count()` should be equal as the `ori_df.count()`, but the `tab_df.count()` give me 0!

Answer (score 0):

use this command :

```
tab_df = ori_df.join(ori_df, ['column_name'])
```

pyspark uses inner join by default

I tried in my computer to join two same tables and it works

Why do you want to join two same tables anyway ?

Comment: just need to verify whether two tables are identical in terms of its data, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Then you can use subtract() method of pyspark.
To know whether the two dataframes are equal.